# NSFetchedResultsController with AFNetworking and MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, afnetworking, magicalrecord

When should I init my NSFetchedResultsController with AFNetworking? Currently I am doing with this:

```
[[AFHttpClient sharedClient] GET:@"/admin/stockCategories" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        NSArray *results = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        if ([results count] > 0) {
            for (NSDictionary *obj in results) {
                StockCategory *category = [StockCategory MR_createEntity];
                category.name = obj[@"name"];
                category.categoryId = obj[@"_id"];
                category.createdDate = [NSDate dateForRFC3339DateTimeString:obj[@"createdDate"]];

                [context MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveParentContexts completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
                }];
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
}];
```

I know normally I put execute fetch request in success block after I saved object to core data. Should I put do this:

```
[context MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveParentContexts completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // add NSFetchedResultsController here ?
    self.fetchedResultsController = [StockCategory MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"createdDate" ascending:NO withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}];
```

if so, self.fetchedResultsController will be init multiple times. I don't think so. What I am currently do is this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        _fetchedResultsController = [StockCategory MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"createdDate" ascending:NO withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But in my UITableViewDatasource methods, only numberOfRows method works, but the cell.textLabel.text is empty. But if I relaunch the simulator, and comment the afnetworking get method. everything works, objects have been saved the core data, and NSFetchedResultsController works too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is...

Comment: @casademora You can see I am saving in a for loop, and after the saving it's done. The table view reload data and the it's data source is coming from fetched results controller. My question is where when and where should I init this fetched results controller during the objects are saving into core data.